# Two different graphic card on a pc

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, dvi

I have a 144hz monitor with dvi dual-link input and an RTX 2060 with only displayport & hdmi output. So I cannot achieve 144hz with hdmi. I have to buy an active DP to dvi duallink adaptor for that to work. My question is, can I use a second graphic card (for example gtx 650) that has dvi output only for display? and all the processing on the RTX 2060? Just to achieve 144hz.

Comment: No you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add two more more different graphics cards without many problems. That is assuming:

- Enough free PCI-e slots (well, duh!),
- A big enough power supply
- And the right drivers for your OS.

The last tended to be a problem. If you have win98 though XP it will be a nightmare or impossible. If you have win7 or more modern than it should just work. Even when mixing several different cards  (E.g. one Matrox, one AMD, one Nvidia should even work).

Now **gaming** on two different graphics cards is something else.

With DX12 it should be possible to mix graphics cards and have the 2060 help with calculations and output on the 650. With olders DX versions and SLI you might archive 144Hz, but not gain the benefit from the RTX2060.

Comment: You cannot mix a GTX 660 with a GTX 2060 in SLI.  SLI only works with equal GPUs.  multi-GPU DX12 is not always supported by the application.

Comment: Nods. That is what I meant with "ut not gain the benefit from the RTX2060". Think I should make that more explicit?

Comment: It was a general statement.  Most people don’t understand how SLI works.  It’s more like putting two identical boxes in a single box, they share the content between them, and each box must contain the same amount of content as the other.  So if one is smaller the larger box can only hold the amount the smaller box can hold.  Horrible example I am sure :-$

Comment: But easily understandable. :)